# Add elements from SwiftyJSON to URL array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm retrieving a list of URL images using Alamofire. The response is in JSON And I have used SwiftyJSON to parse and print each element. I want the URLs to be added into a URL array. Below is the code I have used

```
var newArray = [URL(string: "http://www.tummyvision.com/users/uploads/gijovarghese141@gmail.com/photos/4.jpg")]

        Alamofire.request("http://www.tummyvision.com/users/login/get-images.php", parameters: parameters).responseData { response in
            let json = JSON(data: response.result.value!)
            for i in 0..<json.count
            {
                print(json[i]) // prints the correct url
                self.urlArray.append(json[i])
            }
        }
```

But it is giving me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `arrayValue` property of JSON to access array also you need to convert `String` Url to `URL` object before adding it into Array of `URL`.

```
if let urls = json.arrayValue {
    for url in urls {
        self.urlArray.append(URL(string:url))
    }
}
```